# c++ no suitable conversion function from "const BinaryBuffer" to "int *"

Tags: c++, binary, key, type-conversion

how can i fix this to be able to compile it?
Ive got 3 files and i reeally need help!

I hope u will be able to do so as i hvae tried everything i know :(

FILES:

---

Encrypt.cpp

```
#include "Encrypt.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

#pragma intrinsic(_rotl8, _rotr8)

constexpr auto xorKeyLocation = 0;
constexpr auto numberOfBitsToRotateLocation = 1;

int* Encrypt(const BinaryBuffer& plainText, const EncryptionKey& key)
{
    const auto xorKey = key[xorKeyLocation];
    const auto numberOfBitsToRotate = key[numberOfBitsToRotateLocation];
    const BinaryBuffer result;

    do
    {
        std::transform(
            plainText.begin(),
            plainText.end(),
            std::back_inserter(result),
            [&](const auto byte)
        {
            const auto xored = byte ^ xorKey;
            const auto shifted = _rotl8(xored, numberOfBitsToRotate);

            return shifted;
        });
    } while (0);

    return result;
}

char* Decrypt(const BinaryBuffer& cipherText, const EncryptionKey& key)
{
    const auto xorKey = key[xorKeyLocation];
    const auto numberOfBitsToRotate = key[(std::vector<int>)numberOfBitsToRotateLocation];
    const BinaryBuffer result;

    std::transform(
        cipherText.cbegin(),
        cipherText.cend(),
        std::back_inserter(result),
        [&](const double byte)
    {
        const auto shifted = _rotr8(byte, numberOfBitsToRotate);
        const auto xored = shifted ^ xorKey;
        return xored;
    });

    return result;
}
```

---

Encrypt.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "Comm.h"

BinaryBuffer Encrypt(const BinaryBuffer& plainText, const EncryptionKey& key);
BinaryBuffer Decrypt(const BinaryBuffer& cipherText, const EncryptionKey& key);
```

---

Comm.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>

using BinaryBuffer = std::vector<unsigned char>;
using EncryptionKey = BinaryBuffer;
```

Can anyone help me please?
Thanks :)

Comment: What have you tried? what errors did they return?

Comment: good luck "Shabaknik" .. try solving the challenges on your own .. -1 for trying to cheat...

Comment: You really should not publish that, have some respect.

Comment: @Mortalus eh? cheat? what do u mean?

Comment: @TtheTank Why not? :O

Comment: http://10100110110100001100001011000100110000101101011.com/Homebase/1_can_you_code.php that is all i have to say .. Having other people solving this for you will not prove anything

Comment: @AnonymousUser you know why not otherwise u will not have created a new user for this post.

Comment: @Mortalus :O m friend has given this to me.. I had no idea its frpm there ^_^

Answer (score 0):

These forward declarations in `Encrypt.h`:

```
BinaryBuffer Encrypt(const BinaryBuffer& plainText, const EncryptionKey& key);
BinaryBuffer Decrypt(const BinaryBuffer& cipherText, const EncryptionKey& key);
```

Do not match the implementations in `Encrypt.cpp`. They are forward-declared to return `BinaryBuffer` but the implementations return `int*` and `char*` respectively (which should trigger another compile-time error since you can't overload on return type).  So when you try to `return result;`, the compiler is inferring that you want to convert your local `BinaryBuffer` object to those types of pointers, and there is no available implicit conversion operator for that.

Change the return types of your functions in `Encrypt.cpp` to `BinaryBuffer`.

---

Side note, the `result` variables should not be declared `const`.  You modify them indirectly via `std::back_inserter()`, which will lead to another compilation error.

Comment: Thanks a lot! i dont even know why i did it!! :D but, there is still an issue, in Encrypt.cpp, line 37 "const auto numberOfBitsToRotate = key[(std::vector<int>)numberOfBitsToRotateLocation];" im getting the error "no operator "[]" matches these operands: const EncryptionKey [ std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>> ]"...

can u help me sort it please?

Comment: @AnonymousUser That whole expression makes no sense. `numberOfBitsToRotateLocation` is of type `int` but you are casting it to `std::vector<int>` and then trying to use that to index an `std::vector<unsigned char>`. Converting `int` to `std::vector<int>` is nonsensical, as is attempting to index a vector with another vector. I'm not sure what you need to do to fix it because I'm not sure what it's supposed to be doing in the first place.

Comment: I know, i was given this as a task to repair it and make it compile... I will **VERY** appreciate if you will help me!

Comment: @AnonymousUser "Make it compile" and "make it work correctly" are two different goals. I can help with the first but am unlikely to be able to effectively help with the second.

Comment: Please help me with the first one :)

Comment: @AnonymousUser For example you could replace the body of both functions with `return BinaryBuffer();` to fix the compile-time error, but that's probably not what you want. I'm guessing that this line should be `const auto numberOfBitsToRotate = key[numberOfBitsToRotateLocation];` but this is speculation, and **speculation is dangerous in code that does cryptography.**

Comment: even if i have `const auto numberOfBitsToRotate = key[numberOfBitsToRotateLocation];` there is still compiling error. any idea why?

Comment: @AnonymousUser Not if you don't tell me what the error is.

Comment: the error is `'std::vector<unsigned char,std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_back': 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer`...

Comment: @AnonymousUser As I mentioned before, the two `result` variables should not be `const` if you are trying to modify them.